# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined can't seem to find the mistake

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The variables I have declared (globally):

```
var audio;
var LANGUAGE;
var audioArray;
var MEDIAARRAY;
var WORDS;
var SOUNDARRAY;
```

This is the line that causes the error:

```
var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
```

This is the complete function / ajax call:

```
function setMainObjectArray() {
var exercises = [];
var eBlocks = $('.eBlock');

eBlocks.each(function(i, eBlock) {
    var exObject = {
      word: $(eBlock).find('input.ExerciseGetWordInput').val(),
      audio: '',
      syllables: []
    };

  exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'] = $(this).find('input.exerciseGetWordInput').val();
       var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
        var audio_link = '';
           if (audioId > -1) {
               exObject['audio'] = 'https://test.diglin.eu' + MEDIAARRAY.audio.path + MEDIAARRAY.audio.files[audioId];
           }


    $(eBlock).find('input.syllable').each(function(j, syll) {

      exObject.syllables.push($(syll).val());            
    });

    exercises.push(exObject);
  });

return exercises;
}
```

Where I create the ajax call to save it:

```
function saveExerciseAjaxCall() {
  console.log(setMainObjectArray());


    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveJson.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: getUrlParameter('id'),
            getExerciseTitle: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
            language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
            application: 'lettergrepen',
            'main_object': {
              title: $('#getExerciseTitle').val(),
              language: $('#languageSelector').val(),
              exercises: setMainObjectArray()
              },
              dataType: 'json'
            }
    }).done(function(response) {

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(jqXHR);
      console.log(errorThrown);
      console.log(textStatus);
    });
}
```

Question: What causes this to happen and why?

My understanding: According to this website: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined it's because I am trying `toLowerCase` something that hasn't been defined, but how can this be? I surely DO give a value to `exerciseGetWordInput`.

The function where it should take the value from:

```
function getWordInput(id, cValue) {
cValue = cValue || '';
var wInput = $('<input/>', {
    'class': 'exerciseGetWordInput_' + id + ' form-group form-control ExerciseGetWordInput word',  
    'type': 'text',
    'value': cValue,
    'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord['+ exerciseAudioInput +']',
    'placeholder': 'Exercise',
    'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput',
    'required': true
 });
 return wInput;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div  id='my_form' class="container-fluid" method="POST">
   <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2"><select name="language" class="languageSelector form-control required" id="languageSelector"></select></div></div>
  <button id='resetInputs' type='button' onclick='getResetInputs()' class='btn btn-danger fa fa-refresh fa-2x resetInputs'></button>
  <button id='saveBtn' class='btn btn-info fa fa-download fa-2x saveBtn' required name="submit" onclick="saveExerciseAjaxCall()"></button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is `MEDIAARRAY` defined? Does it have an `audio` property attached to it?

Comment: Post the HTML.. looks like your selector is wrong.

Comment: Everything I have is made up from jquery/javascript funtions. I could post those?

Comment: That's more complicated than needed, better to post the HTML itself when you're calling `saveExerciseAjaxCall`

Comment: oh oke... my bad, let me change that then. although I do have to say: It works without the audio part.

Comment: Check this line:
`exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'] = $(this).find('input.exerciseGetWordInput').val();`
maybe it causes in `exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'] = undefined`

Comment: There is no `.eBlock` in the HTML, you posted, nor is there any `input.exerciseGetWordInput` in your HTML......

Comment: As stated before: Pretty much everything has been made with jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here, you are missing `)` in indexOf:

```
var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase() + '.mp3');
```

Try with:

```
var audioId = MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput']).toLowerCase() + '.mp3';
```

Comment: When I use urs it throws in a pink notification (saying it has not been opened or closed). Going by ur answer you have a total of 3 brackets. 2 which close 1 which opens?

Comment: Also remove the round bracket after '.mp3' in your suggestion

Comment: throws in the error: Uncaught TypeError: MEDIAARRAY.audio.lowercase.indexOf(...).toLowerCase is not a function?

Comment: when you do console.log(exObject['exerciseGetWordInput']); before the line. What output do you get can you post it please

Answer (score 0):

`.toLowerCase()` not `lowercase`.

`lowercase` is not javascript function.

Comment: That's not the issue. error is raised due to `exObject['exerciseGetWordInput'].toLowerCase()`